# Chained (piped) greps ignore metacharacters?

Tags: grep, wildcard

I am having trouble searching for lines with `.` in complex (chained) grep commands.
Is this my error or a bug?

```
grep '\.' filename | grep 1    # works correctly (finds lines with '.' and '1')
grep 1 filename | grep '\.'    # fails: ignores 2nd grep, returns lines with or without '.'
```

It is not the pipe that causes this; it is really something about grep.
This frankly seems implausible, yet it is true:

```
cat filename | grep 1 | grep '\.'   # works correctly (and provides an easy work-around for the bug)
```

Adding more protection does not help:

```
grep 1 filename | grep '\\.'      # fails
```

If there is a something behind or in front of the wildcard, it works:

```
grep 1 filename | grep 'a\.'     #  works
grep 1 filename | grep '\.a'     #  works
```

But not if the something is a range:

```
grep 1 filename | grep '[0-9]\.'    # fails
grep 1 filename | grep '\.[0-9]'    # fails
```

I can't believe this is really a bug - I must be missing something, right?

Thanks!

```
uname -a
Linux conception 2.6.32-33-generic #70-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 7 21:09:46 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: For kicks, have you tried a control test using `fgrep`?

Comment: It will be great to see your `filename` and grep version.

Comment: OK, I *was* doing something dumb.  I was using a wildcard to look at a bunch of files at once:   `grep 1 filenam* | grep '\.'`, and the filename had a '.' in it.  Should have spotted it right off - sorry for the bother!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, "chained" grep command is something like "mauvais ton". Most of times `grep | grep` can be replaced with one `grep` with complicated regular expression.

Grepping lines with `.` and `1` in it.

```
$> cat ./text | grep -P "(\..*1|1.*\.)"
line with 1 and . in it
```

`-P` means perl regex
`"(\..*1|1.*\.)"` is (`.`, some symbols and `1`) or (`1`, some symbols and `.`)

So, if you not pretty sure about wildcards usage, regular expressions could be your useful, safe, and powerful tool.

```
$> cat ./text 
line without anything
another line
line with.ok
and one another
line with 1
some text

line with 1 and . in it
empty line
last line
```

First examples `grep '\.' filename | grep 1`, `grep 1 filename | grep '\.'`, `cat filename | grep 1 | grep '\.'` returnes right answer

```
line with 1 and . in it
```

Second example `grep 1 filename | grep '\\.'` failed because you're grepping `\` with any symbol after it.

Comment: So for you, grep 1 filename | grep '\.'

Answer (score 0):

My stupid error.

I was grep'ing a bunch of files, and the filename itself contained a '.':

```
cat one.file
    1
    2
    3

cat second.file  
    10  
    11  
    12.
```

Now

```
grep 1 *file | grep '\.'

  one.file: 1  
  second.file: 10  
  second.file: 11  
  second.file: 12.
```

I looked at the output and thought that the 2nd grep was being ignored.  Obvious now what is going on, but really threw me this morning.